# Копирование файлов в Delphi

Tags: delphi

Как можно скопировать все файлы из одной папки в другую папку?

Answer (score 3):

1) Получаем все файлы из заданной директории, 
   используя комбинацию **findfirst->findnext->findclose:**

```
procedure copypast(dir:string; to_dir:string);
var fn:TSearchRec;
begin
dir:=includetrailingbackslash(dir);
to_dir:=includetrailingbackslash(to_dir);
if findfirst(dir+'*',faanyfile,fn)<>0 then exit;  // * - любые файлы 
copyfile(Pchar(dir+fn.name),Pchar(to_dir+fn.name),true);
while findnext(fn)=0  do
copyfile(Pchar(dir+fn.name),Pchar(to_dir+fn.name),true);
findclose(fn);
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Средствами `WinAPI`: смотрите раздел [File Management Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364232(v=vs.85).aspx). Там есть полный набор функций, [CopyFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364232(v=vs.85).aspx), `FindFirstFile`, `FindNextFile` и т.д.

Answer (score 2):

А так пойдёт? Код модуля:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, FileCtrl, Buttons, Gauges;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    BitBtn1: TBitBtn;
    GroupBox1: TGroupBox;
    DirectoryListBox1: TDirectoryListBox;
    FileListBox1: TFileListBox;
    DriveComboBox1: TDriveComboBox;
    GroupBox2: TGroupBox;
    DirectoryListBox2: TDirectoryListBox;
    FileListBox2: TFileListBox;
    DriveComboBox2: TDriveComboBox;
    GaugeFile: TGauge;
    GaugeAll: TGauge;
    procedure BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
Var
  F1, F2: File Of Char;
  Buf: Array[1..2048] Of Char;
  SizeFile, SizeRead: Int64;
  ColRead, ColWrite: Integer;
  i, n: Word;
  FName: String;
begin
  N:=FileListBox1.Items.Count-1;
  GaugeAll.MaxValue:=N+1;

  {$I-}

  For i:=0 To N Do
    Begin
      FName:=DirectoryListBox1.Directory+'\'+FileListBox1.Items.Strings[i];
      AssignFile(F1, FName);
      AssignFile(F2, DirectoryListBox2.Directory+'\'+FileListBox1.Items.Strings[i]);
      Try
        ReSet(F1);
        SizeFile:=FileSize(F1);
        ReWrite(F2);

        ColRead:=0;
        ColWrite:=0;
        SizeRead:=0;
        Screen.Cursor:=crHourGlass;
        While (ColRead=ColWrite) Do
          Begin
            BlockRead(F1, Buf, SizeOf(Buf), ColRead);
            If (ColRead=0) Then Break;
            BlockWrite(F2, Buf, ColRead, ColWrite);
            SizeRead:=SizeRead+ColRead;
            GaugeFile.Progress:=Round(100*SizeRead/SizeFile);
            Application.ProcessMessages;
          End;
        GaugeAll.Progress:=GaugeAll.Progress+1;
        Screen.Cursor:=crDefault;
      Finally
        CloseFile(F1);
        CloseFile(F2);
      End;
    End;

  {$I+}
end;

end.
```

Интерфейс программы:
[image]

Comment: Большое спасибо!!! Правда я хотел через компонент OpenDialog или как там называется?!!

Comment: Ох...жесть =)  И вы для этого целую программу писали?

Comment: Нууу.... не только для этого!!!